# Unable to recover data with GetDataBack?

Tags: windows-7, data-recovery

Recently, I recovered data with GetDataBack software => http://www.runtime.org/data-recovery-software.htm
all of my data get backed with true name and size.
The sound files don't have any problems and I can open it but around 50% of another files like ***.pdf*** , **.doc** and the files don't open at all. it likes you open a pdf file with none related software.
the name and size is correct but I cannot open them !

Could you please guide me?

Answer (score 2):

### GetDataBack is no magician

Even though **GetDataBack** may be one of the best recovery programs it may not do magic. When files are unrecoverable they're unrecoverable. GDB may find their names, paths etc, but data may be invalid hence you won't be able to use those files any more.

Happened to me as well. Although it looked promising I bought the license but eventually it turned out that vast majority of these files were invalid.

But it was mainly my fault since I accidentally repartitioned my disk and reinstalled Windows on top of full formatted drive.

But some files were fine nonetheless.